# Whats the purpose of getting daily DMARC reports from google about my Mail Server?

Tags: email, email-server, dmarc, spoofing

I've been getting DMARC reports from google everyday after setting this up on my domain to prevent domain spoofing. Do I really need to have this daily report? I've never opened the attached zip file before. I have a very small site with less than 10 users using it. It's not a high traffic or high value site.

- Do I really need the DMARC daily report? What is the intended purpose of it?
- How should I turn it off?
- What are some scenarios where I would have needed this report?

Comment: `Do I really need to have this daily report?` - Do you? We can't answer that question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reports are statistics of the mail flow from your domain and its DMARC alignment (SPF and DKIM) results. You could use them to see how much your domain is spoofed or for finding out if legitimate mail is (or would be) rejected or quarantined. Without the reports you'd lose that information.

The reports are in XML format and you get a lot of them. It might be better to automate the analysis or use an external service for it. There are services that can receive your reports directly, analyse them and give you nice graphical reports.

You can turn off the XML reports by removing  `rua=mailto:foo@example.com;` from your DMARC record (and `ruf=` for forensic reports).

Comment: what services can analyze it for me? I just change the email to them?

Comment: It depends on the service, and SF is not for service recommendations. Some are based on file uploads, some can be used directly. Some are free, some are not. You got all the keywords for a little googling by now.